# PHP Text highlighter

Tags: php

I have an script which gets the content of webpage by cURL, Now i have to highlight some keywords in that. str_replace is not working beacuse if i replace 'a', than all  will be replaced and that will create a problem.

Please can anybody help?

Comment: Do you need to highlight certain words or do you need full HTML syntaxt highlightning?

Comment: i want to highlight text in full HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to highlight words you can use the ***preg_replace*** function like that :

```
foreach($myKeywords as $keyword)
     $myNewCode = preg_replace("/[\\s*\\.,](".$keyword.")[\\s*\\.,]/",'<span class="highlight">${1}</span>',$myCode);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want something fully customizable and with lots of features, [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) has you covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `' a '` instead of just `'a'` if you want to use str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

use preg_rplace  function......

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would only handle this on the client side, for one reason only, don't reinvent the wheel or mess around if you don't need to.

I did exactly what you are asking by utilizing a plugin for jquery:

**JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin**

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

What you do is basically in the `<head>` of your HTML create an entry like:

`$('body').removeHighlight().highlight('<?php echo "text to highlight"; ?>');`

Easy as pie, and don't have to tinker with anything